# Overriding base address fields of res.partner with custom functionality

Tags: field, openerp-7

I am working on customization of openerp which is UK specific so I want to override fields of res.partner like zip and state_id. I want to use post codes instead of zip and County instead of state. There are also some apps which depend on these fields so I don't want to add new ones. The zip should remain the same but instead of zip I want it to use post code lookup for which I have the model. The state_id field should also be used as county.

The postcode model has the following fields (Data is not real)

```
   _________________________________________________________________________
   | PostCode_id | Postcode | longitude | Longitude |    Town   | County   |
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |      1      |   'AS34' |  53454    | 435345    | Aberdeen  | Aberdeen |
   .........................................................................
   | ....
```

I want the zip to be a many2one field, when the user type the postcode it should offer auto completion. The base **zip** field in **res.partner** is of type **'char'**. The state_id is a many2one field but I want to connect it to **county** column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Basically setting postcode column as _rec_name solved the issue. It is also a good idea to make another table or model for county and to add foreign key in this table. This way I was able to achieve what I wanted.
Thanks anyways